# Maximo Anywhere Tasks for new work order

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

Not able to create tasks for new work order from Anywhere. Please suggest

1. Able to create a new work order without task
2. Added a new view for tasks, and trying to add taskId, status, Asset with lookup and Location with lookup.

lookup are not visible in UI. Here is my code

```
<view id="WorkExecution.NewAdhocWorkOrderInspTaskView" label="Create Inspection Tasks"  >
        <requiredResources id="WorkExecution.NewAdhocWorkOrderInspTaskView_requiredResources">
            <requiredResource id="WorkExecutionAdhocINspTaskView.NewAdhocWorkOrderView_additionalasset" name="additionalasset"/>

        </requiredResources>

        <container id="WorkExecution.NewAdhocWorkOrderInspTaskView_workOrder_container_0" resource="AdhocWOInspTaskResource" >
            <group id="WorkExecution.NewAdhocWorkOrderInspTaskView_group_0">            
                <groupitem id="WorkExecution.NewAdhocWorkOrderInspTaskView_workOrder_groupitem_4" >
                    <text editable="true" id="WorkExecution.NewAdhocWorkOrderView_groupitem_WorkExecution0.Asset" label="Asset2" layoutInsertAt="item1"
                    lookup="WorkExecutionAdhocWOInsptask" lookupAttribute="assetnum" placeHolder="Tap to enter1" resourceAttribute="InspTaskAssetNum" />
                </groupitem>
            </group>
        </container>
 </view>

   <resource additionalData="true" id="AdhocWO_InsptaskResource" name="AdhocWOInspTaskResource" describedBy="http://jazz.net/ns/ism/asset/smarter_physical_infrastructure#WoActivity" providedBy="/oslc/sp/SmarterPhysicalInfrastructure" >
        <attributes id="AdhocWO_InsptaskResource_attributes">
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:taskid" id="AdhocWO_InsptaskResource_spi_taskid" name="InspTaskId"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:assetnum" id="AdhocWO_InsptaskResource_spi_AssetNum" name="InspTaskAssetNum"/> 

            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:location" id="AdhocWO_InsptaskResource_spi_Location" name="InspTaskLocation"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:status" id="AdhocWO_InsptaskResource_spi_Status" name="InspTaskStatus"/>                
        </attributes>           
    </resource>

<resource additionalData="true" describedBy="http://open-services.net/ns/asset#Asset" id="additionalasset" name="additionalasset" pageSize="1000" providedBy="/oslc/sp/AssetManagement">
        <attributes id="additionalasset_attributes">
            <attribute describedByProperty="dcterms:identifier" id="additionalasset_assetuid_dctermsidentifier" name="assetuid"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:assetid" id="additionalasset_assetid_spiassetid" name="assetid"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:orgid" id="additionalasset_orgid_spiorgid" index="true" name="orgid"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:siteid" id="additionalasset_siteid_spisiteid" index="true" isExactMatchIndex="true" name="siteid"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="oslc:shortTitle" id="additionalasset_assetnum_oslcshortTitle" index="true" name="assetnum"/>

        </attributes>
        <queryBases id="additionalasset_queryBases">
            <queryBase id="additionalasset_queryBase_getadditionalasset" name="getadditionalasset" queryUri="/oslc/os/oslcasset"/>
        </queryBases>           
        <whereClause id="additionalasset_whereClause"/>
    </resource>

<lookup id="WorkExecutionAdhocWOInsptask" label="Select Asset" resource="additionalasset">
         <requiredResources id="WorkExecutionAdhocWO_Insptask.AssetLookup_requiredResources">
            <requiredResource id="WorkExecutionAdhocWO_Insptask.AssetLookup_additionalasset" name="additionalasset"/> 
            <requiredResource id="WorkExecutionAdhocWO_Insptask.AssetLookup_workOrder" name="AdhocWOInspTaskResource"/>
        </requiredResources>

        <list id="WorkExecutionAdhocWO_Insptask.AssetLookup_additionalasset_list" resource="additionalasset">

            <listItemTemplate id="WorkExecutionAdhocWO_Insptask.AssetLookup_additionalasset_listItemTemplate_Item2Desc2" layout="Item2Desc2">
                <listtext cssClass="bold textappearance-medium" id="WorkExecutionAdhocWO_Insptask.AssetLookup_additionalasset_Item2Desc2_assetnum" layoutInsertAt="item1" resourceAttribute="assetnum"/>
                <listtext cssClass="bold textappearance-medium" id="WorkExecutionAdhocWO_Insptask.AssetLookup_additionalasset_Item2Desc2_description" layoutInsertAt="desc1" resourceAttribute="description"/>
                <listtext id="WorkExecutionAdhocWO_Insptask.AssetLookup_additionalasset_Item2Desc2_location" layoutInsertAt="item2" resourceAttribute="location"/>
                <listtext id="WorkExecutionAdhocWO_Insptask.AssetLookup_additionalasset_Item2Desc2_locationdesc" layoutInsertAt="desc2" resourceAttribute="locationdesc"/>
            </listItemTemplate>
        </list>

        <returnAttributes id="WorkExecutionAdhocWO_Insptask.AssetLookup_returnAttributes">
            <returnAttribute id="WorkExecutionAdhocWO_Insptask.AssetLookup_assetnum_asset" sourceAttribute="assetnum" targetAttribute="InspTaskAssetNum" />             
        </returnAttributes>

    </lookup>
```

Comment: Can you post some information about your view that you've added.  That's what should be referencing this new Lookup.

Comment: Here is my view, edited my actual post