# Maximo Anywhere - Debugging

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

My lookup attribute is not detectable or visible in the UI, not able to trace the root cause. looking for debugging tips and techniques of UI(app.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow these instructions, and add the lookup to the new View you've created

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.6.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/config_apps/t_add_flds_domains.html

Comment: Yes. I have followed all the instructions. My actual code is in post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933749/maximo-anywhere-tasks-for-new-work-order